# Alarm manager delay not working

Tags: android

Hi,

I use the following code snippet to invoke an action after a delay using the AlarmManager. But the alarm is invoked immediately.

AlarmUtility.java

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);    
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 *24*3600,
            1000 *24*3600, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    } // trying to first trigger the alarm after 24 hrs and repeat after 24 hours
```

Please let me know what is my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1000 *24*3600` is definitely in the past and so, the alarm will [trigger immediately](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> If the time occurs in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the
>   trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

Instead get the current time then add 24 hours for the inital wakeup:

```
Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add (Calendar.DATE,1);
long day = 1000 *24*3600;

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), day , pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

u should use like this:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time, time, pi);
```

and if u r want to use `1000 *24*3600`, then use `(1000 *24*3600)L`. because `1000 *24*3600` is larger than `Integer.Max_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon first look the problem seems to be with

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000 *24*3600,
        1000 *24*3600, pi);
```

The second parameter triggerAtTime should point to a time, when the alarm should go off. It should not be a time interval.

Check the below sample:

```
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 *24*3600,
        1000 *24*3600, pi);
```